# Git - Unable to commit, asks for username, but unable to insert username

Tags: git, azure-pipelines

I am unable to commit as it asks for a username. However, when I try to add a username, I am unable to

[image: I censored out personal details however the gist should still be there]

Comment: `user.name`, not `user,name`.

Comment: @tkausl Sorry for wasting your time, I'm extremely blind. Please post it as an answer and I'll mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a dot `.` instead of a comma `,`, i.e. `user.name` and `user.email`.